# Google Maps is registered the touch in wrong place

Tags: angularjs, cordova, google-maps, monaca

I'm making a cordova-angular app and google maps is registering the touch-event in the wrong place (see picture). Any ideas of what can be wrong?

[Picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVtZh.jpg)

Comment: Is it just for markers ? Can you post a minimal example see here for more details : http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ?

Comment: I found out that its related to that I have zoomed the browser window. I made an example here http://jsfiddle.net/ds4jdebo/
It is the same both on a laptop and a mobile.